# Support for additional Filesystems on Ubuntu Core

Tags: mount, filesystem, ubuntu-core, exfat, fuse

I'm trying to mount an external Hard Drive formatted with exFAT on Ubuntu-core (Raspberry Pi edition with snap package manager) but there doesn't seem to be any way of installing the required packages (exFAT fuse) to do so.

There's apparently an existing support for [fuse interfaces on snap](https://docs.snapcraft.io/the-fuse-support-interface/7816) but I can't find any current implementation of it (let alone exFAT).

Am I missing something?